# ip tuntap add gives "open: No such file or directory"

Tags: networking, 20.04, ip, tunnel

I'm inside a dockerized ubuntu 20 and trying to run the command below, but I get this error:

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun user `id -un`

open: No such file or directory
```

tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924094/ip-tuntap-command-cant-open-tun but it didn't work. Anyone knows what's happening? I have installed `iproute2`. Something is missing? I'm root and tried with and without `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker doesn't map in the tun/tap device, so this needs to be done manually.  Use the following flag for docker run.

> --device /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun